# Duplicate sources.list entry

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I received following error and then I tried `apt-get update` to correct it but that didn't work.

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/contrib i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/http.us.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_contrib_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/non-free i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/http.us.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_non-free_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

Comment: Post your sources.list file...

Comment: @Raymond_W Agree to Jason. Without your sources.list file, __nobody__ of us can help - period. So please remember to supply it if you still want help about this issue.

Answer (score 7):

The [`sources.list`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sources.list&sektion=5) file is actually several files: `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and files called `something.list` in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

This message tells you that you have duplicate entries in those files: you have several lines pointing to the same source. This is a warning: it isn't wrong per se, but it indicates that your configuration is probably not right. Look for lines starting with `deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian wheezy` in the files I mentioned above. You have multiple such lines containing `contrib` and `non-free`. Either remove the redundant lines or correct them if you meant for them to point to something else.

Comment: unfortunately this answer did not work for me, I am getting the message but I cannot find any duplicates in sources.list and I can't find any files at all in sources.list.d